# How to use Anchor tag in reactjs if they are coming from API and has internal page linking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In the below paragraph text is coming from API and has two Anchor tags one with External Linking and another with internal linking.

I want to use an anchor tag that has internal linking, as the react-router-dom `<Link />` component.

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://somewhere.com">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet consectetur,
  adipisicing elit. Iusto adipisci ab tenetur dolorem nulla distinctio aliquam?
  Officiis, pariatur nesciunt! Aliquid, deserunt? Dignissimos tempora hic
  accusantium culpa sapiente debitis dolorum quisquam quasi labore magnam? Velit
  facere ut quaerat dicta dolore optio porro soluta aperiam reiciendis voluptas
  mollitia numquam sint, 
  sequi error?<a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the shape of the data you are getting form the API?